# JSON Object parsing

Tags: android, json

I need to parse some JSON object, whihc looks like this:

```
{"searchdata":{},"userdata":{"currency":"69","notificationCount":7}}
```

I using the following code to achieve this:

```
JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(getResponse);
JSONObject jSearchData = rootObj.getJSONObject("searchdata");
JSONObject userData = jSearchData.getJSONObject("userdata");

String currency = userData.getString("currency");
```

I'm not able to print the `currency` object from the above code. I keep getting exception:

```
Exception: org.json.JSONException: No value for userdata
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: less pain ;) : https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(getResponse);
```

`userData` is inside `rootObj` not inside `searchdata`

For null value you should use:

```
isNull

if (!rootObj.isNull("userdata")) {
    JSONObject userData = rootObj.getJSONObject("userdata");
}
```

Comment: Thank You, but how to handle null response from the server. Like this `{"searchdata":{},"userdata":null}`. Whenever I get null response from the server I get this exception: `Exception: org.json.JSONException: Value null at userdata of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject`, because of this my PostExecute() method is giving null response.

Comment: This is not helping me, keep getting `Exception: org.json.JSONException: Value null at userdata of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject`, if the value is null.

Comment: I'm doing this thing: `if (!rootObj.isNull("userdata")) {
     String currency = userData.getString("currency");
     System.out.println("Userdata inside doInBackground: "
       + currency);
    } else {
     System.out.println("Null Value for USERDATA");
    }`

Comment: Ya got that, thanx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
JSONObject userData = rootObj.getJSONObject("userdata");
```

to get `currency`

```
currency  = userData.getString("currency");
```

use like this way...

check object is null..

as per @blackbelt's answer use : `if (!rootObj.isNull("userdata"))`

Comment: Thank You, but how to handel null response from the server like `{"searchdata":{},"userdata":null}`

Comment: I'm always getting this error after I applied your changes. `Exception: org.json.JSONException: Value null at userdata of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject`